# Communicating Data Between Model And View In IOS Programming

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, nstimer, timing, cadisplaylink

I am constructing an iPhone side-scroll video game from the ground up. I have an Enemy model that needs to change the position of an enemy's arms and legs. I need to communicate those changes to the view for display. Should I use an NSTimer inside the model to change those positions, and then have the ViewController observe those changes based on KVO, and have the ViewController send the information to the View, and have the view call setNeedsDisplay? Naturally, I want to have the fastest frame rate possible.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a reasonable way to do it.